# Is there a JpaRepository method which can save a provided password where username condition?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I am looking for a JpaRepository method to update a user provided password at the time of resetting it with a username condition . Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a User entity? So just change it and call save()

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at creating custom query methods with `JPA` as per documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query.

For your use case, the following would allow you update the correct user's password:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {

  @Query("update User u set u.password= ?1 where u.username = ?2")
  void updatePassword(String username, String password);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Data JPA, whenever you execute an update, you need to use the `@Modifying` along with the `@Query`. Failing to use the `@Modifying` will result in `InvalidDataAccessApiUsage` exception.

Find the code below

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {

  @Modifying
  @Query("update User u set u.password= :password where u.username = :username")
  void updatePassword(@Param("username") String username, @Param("password") String password);

}
```